# Significance of 'chiral' form for a qubit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Say I have a qubit with probability amplitude divided evenly among $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|1\rangle$$

So it seems that we have a, loosely speaking, 'symmetric' probability amplitude for the states. However, I read in

> [*Explorations in Quantum Computing*](http://books.google.ie/books?id=QE8S--WjIFwC&q=chiral#v=snippet&q=chiral&f=false). Colin P. Williams (Springer, 2011), p. 392.

that this is not the case and

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|0\rangle + \frac{i}{\sqrt 2}|1\rangle$$

is actually a 'better' representation of a states with a symmetric probability amplitude.

Can someone explain why this is so? The explanation can be very handwavy, I'm looking for some intuition on it why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really what he means in the book you linked to: he's not talking about the probabilities of getting 1 or 0 if you measure that qubit.

His point is that if you start the quantum walk with the coin qubit in the first state you gave, after waiting for a few timesteps, you get a position probability distribution that doesn't look very symmetric about position zero.  If you have the coin qubit in the second state you gave, you get something that looks more symmetric.